# Filtering a github organization's projects by topics

Tags: github

Is there a way to create a link that filters a github organizations by topic?  Under the [superflycss organization](https://github.com/superflycss) i have different types of projects (Utilities, components, tasks) and each projects is tagged with a corresponding topic.  I'd like to provide links that can be clicked on that will display the organization view by a certain topic.  For example:

```
https://github.com/superflycss?topic=utilities
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one way of doing this that is less work.  It allows me to skip adding topics to the project and instead just uses the organizations search field to generate the link.  For utilities I just went to:

```
https://github.com/superflycss
```

And typed `utilities` in the `Search repositories` field, which produces the following URL:

```
https://github.com/superflycss?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=utilities&type=&language=
```

I then use this within other areas to reference the utility projects within the superflycss organization:

[utilities](https://github.com/superflycss?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=utilities&type=&language=)